# How to process the submit_sm_resp over smpp protocol

Tags: java, sms, message, messaging, smpp

I have implemented Sending message over SMPP, everything is fine but as per the SMPP protocol if message are sent to Invalid_destination_address it will reply with  org.smpp.pdu.SubmitSM object which contains following body

(submit_resp: (pdu: 16 80000004 b 880761) 0 (opt: ) )
(submit: (pdu: 117 4 0 880761) (addr: 5 0 SEND) (addr: 0 0 9712688842) (sm: msg: Hi, This is the test sms. Please Ignore.) (opt: ) (extraopt: (oct: (tlv: 5221) 144a58e477301bf1) ) )

how i can extract "b" the mobile number 9712688842

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. B number is in SMPP response already. Can you provide hex stream of full submit_sm_resp.

Answer (score 1):

The B number is not in the SUBMIT_SM_RESP,
But this one has a transaction ID,
So you could retrieve the B number by retrieing the SUBMIT_SM, the Bnumber will be the destination address.